# Why choose "BM algorithm" rather than "Sunday algorithm" in text editor's Find function?

Tags: string, algorithm, language-agnostic, full-text-search

[image]

Under random characters, the Sunday algorithm is faster than the bm algorithm.

So, Why choose "BM algorithm" rather than "Sunday algorithm" in text editor's Find function?

Comment: Maybe due to limited visibility. *D.M. Sunday: A Very Fast Substring Search Algorithm. Communications of the ACM, 33, 8, 132-142 (1990)*? Or due to being, as BM-Horspool, a refinement of BM, and being called just BM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no simple answer to why you'd choose one over the other. The "BM" refers to "Boyer-Moore". The "Sunday" algorithm refers to Sunday's variant of Boyer-Moore-Horspool.

As you can probably guess from the names, Sunday's variant of Boyer-Moore-Horspool is quite a lot like Boyer-Moore.

Truthfully, the primary reason people choose Sunday's variant has little to do with execution speed. Rather, it's quite a bit simpler to implement. The original Boyer-Moore algorithm is dreadfully difficult to get entirely correct. Sunday's variant isn't entirely trivial either, but it's still quite a bit simpler.

The argument in favor of Boyer-Moore is that although the code is more complex, it reduces the number of comparisons required for a search to a close approximation of the minimum absolutely necessary. The big problem is that it requires more preprocessing (and more memory) to do that.

You can find cases that favor either one over the other in terms of execution speed (but, from what I've seen) use of search in text editors probably tends to favor Sunday's variant of Boyer-Moore-Horspool.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am concerned,

Full vertion Boyer-Moore algorithm speed up string matching by two table: `delta1` and `delta2`
which are also known as *bad suffix table* and *good prefix table*.

If alphabet is large, for example ascii scope or one-byte scope (0-255), `delta1` plays main role of in matching. Otherwise, for tiny alphabet, for example DNA (4 size alphabet), `delta2` works more than `delta1`.

For delta2 needs a little complexed preprocessing (if write time complexity O(n) code)
and more memory (it holds an extra alphabet table), Simplified-Boyer-Moore algorithm just use the `delta1` table. It works fine in common case.

Horspool algorithm is one of Simplified-Boyer-Moore algorithm, Sunday algorithm  is an improved version of Horspool algorithm.

The text editor don't care about a little more memory load (at most 256 byte), full version Boyer Moore algorithm is a more reasonable choice.